# How well-known are the Manic Street Preachers in the US?

Tags: rock

I'm an expat Brit living in the US and I've always been a big fan of the Manic Street Preachers, who are a Welsh band that are generally considered one of the best British rock bands of the 90s. Their music couples catchy, hard-rock riffs with philosophical, political and sometimes dark lyrics.

I'm wondering how widely known they are in the US. I'm sure they have toured here and some of their albums have sold here, but not sure to what extent. Would American fans of 90s-era rock be likely to know of them? If so, what would be their best-known song in the US? I'm wondering if I was to recommend them to someone, what songs by the Manics might they know?

Comment: I only ever heard of them because my ex-girlfriend was British...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In U.S.A., Manic Street Preachers have put on some live tours in different years, so they can't be completely unknown.

But there's no trace of them in the list of Golden Record and other RIAA prizes.

If we analyze their numbers:

Total live shows: **963**

Total USA live shows: **50**

Percentage: About 5% of their total live tours were in the US.

You can see [**here**](https://www.songkick.com/artists/239460-manic-street-preachers/) about this number.

I've found USA live tours in these pages:

[Page 5 - 10 USA live shows](https://www.songkick.com/artists/239460-manic-street-preachers/gigography?page=5)

[Page 10 - 10 USA live shows](https://www.songkick.com/artists/239460-manic-street-preachers/gigography?page=10)

[Page 11 - 1 USA lives shows](https://www.songkick.com/artists/239460-manic-street-preachers/gigography?page=11)

[Page 12 - 6 USA lives shows](https://www.songkick.com/artists/239460-manic-street-preachers/gigography?page=12)

[Page 13 - 17 USA lives shows](https://www.songkick.com/artists/239460-manic-street-preachers/gigography?page=13)

[Page 17 - 6 USA lives shows](https://www.songkick.com/artists/239460-manic-street-preachers/gigography?page=17)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, it seems their records have not sold particularly well in the US, but they have done some live tours. Still, 50 shows over 30-odd years doesn't seem to be a huge number.

Comment: @Time4Tea: Yes is not a huge number. If my answer accomplish your aim, please accept it (I write so, because you're a newbie). Have a nice day

Comment: 50 shows or 50 tours?

Comment: @colmde 50 shows, Ok i fix my answer. Thank you for your appointment